# Visual studio relative path macro to projects location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, relative-path

Is there a macro in Visual Studio 2010 which refers to the "Projects location" as specified under Options > Projects and Solutions > General? I would like to set up some includes relative to this location rather than specifying an absolute path.

For example, if my default project location is:

```
c:\projects
```

And I have a project at:

```
c:\projects\solution1\project1
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
$(ProjectsDir)\<mypath>
```

The closest I've found is to do:

```
$(SolutionDir)\..\<mypath>
```

But that means that if I ever relocate my solution, the path will break.